# Facebook, Spotify (iOS) using MPVolumeView or custom view to bring airplay?

Tags: ios, facebook, spotify, airplay, mpvolumeview

I am working on a voip app and want to route audio to bluetooth. I learned that the only way to do is to bring up airplay menu using MPVolumeView. The downside of the MPVolumeView is that it is not very customizeable. I looked at facebook and spotify outlook app and find that they both have customized it more than what is provided by the MPVolumeView API. I am wondering if they are really using the MPVOlumeView or that have a custom view and programatically send tap event to the button inside MPVolumeView?

Comment: Did you figure anything out? I'm in a situation myself where I've been looking for an answer to this.

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful: you can change the image of the button as the Spotify app does by inspecting the current audio session route, and using the routeButtonImage customizer API on MPVolumeView.

```
let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance( )
if let output = audioSession.currentRoute.outputs.first
{
    let myCustomImage = <#Use information from the output (AVAudioSessionPortDescription) to set a custom image #>
    myVolumeView.setRouteButtonImage( myCustomImage, for: .normal )

}
```